# merging 2 files with different structure

Tags: tcl

want to merge 2 files **proc_2.tcl** to the **proc_1.tcl**  , by using *name* , *layer* , *bbox*,

file **ports_1.tcl** below:

```
create_terminal \
        -name {DMItoPCUNotL1XnnnH} \
        -port {DMItoPCUNotL1XnnnH} \
        -layer m10 \
        -bbox {{0.000 2.104} {0.320 2.184}}

set obj [get_terminal {"DMItoPCUNotL1XnnnH"}]
set_attribute -quiet $obj layer  m10
set_attribute -quiet $obj owner_port  {DMItoPCUNotL1XnnnH}
set_attribute -quiet $obj bbox {{0.000 2.104} {0.320 2.184}}
set_attribute -quiet $obj status Fixed
set_attribute -quiet $obj access_direction Left
set_attribute -quiet $obj direction input
set_attribute -quiet $obj eeq_class 0
```

file **proc_2.tcl** below:

```
DMItoPCUNotL1XnnnH M8 {{0.000 4} {0.320 5}}

name : DMItoPCUNotL1XnnnH
layer: M8
bbox : {{0.000 4} {0.320 5}}
```

Comment: The files shown aren't the ones you say you want to merge, and you provided no useful information as to how you wish to merge them.  Nor have you shown *any* effort at solving this yourself.

Comment: but i still do not understood what is the solution ?!

Comment: Are we talking about running the code in the first file (or something derived from it) in a situation where values are taken from the second file somehow? I'm not sure I understand what bits are going where yet...

Comment: need to take bbox of port from proc_2.tcl & put it in ports_1.tcl in every line i got bbox :

Comment: example : in proc_1.tcl 
> -bbox {{0.000 2.104} {0.320 2.184}}  
i want it will be replaced by data from proc_2.tcl
>  bbox : {{0.000 4} {0.320 5}}

Comment: oh - the main file is ports_1.tcl

Comment: i think need somehow to parse the files & update the relevant fields .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the second file is this:

```
DMItoPCUNotL1XnnnH M8 {{0.000 4} {0.320 5}}
```

Then it can be parsed and converted/generated as something like the first one using this:

```
set TEMPLATE {
    create_terminal \
            -name {$name} \
            -port {$name} \
            -layer $layer \
            -bbox {$bbox}
    set obj [get_terminal {"$name"}]
    set_attribute -quiet \$obj layer $layer
    set_attribute -quiet \$obj owner_port {$name}
    set_attribute -quiet \$obj bbox {$bbox}
    set_attribute -quiet \$obj status Fixed
    set_attribute -quiet \$obj access_direction Left
    set_attribute -quiet \$obj direction input
    set_attribute -quiet \$obj eeq_class 0
}

set f_in [open "file2.whatever.you.call.it"]
set f_out [open "file1.tcl" w]

# For each line 
while {[gets $f_in line] >= 0} {
    # Skip blank lines or lines that start with # so you have comments
    if {$line eq "" || [string match "#*" [string trim $line]]} continue

    # We assume that each line is a complete Tcl list.
    # This is usually a dodgy idea, but looks good in your specific case.
    lassign $line name layer bbox

    # Now generate the text using subst on the template
    # I disable command substitutions; this reduces the number of backslashes needed
    set text [subst -nocommands $TEMPLATE]

    # Write the substituted text to the output file
    puts $f_out $text
}

close $f_in
close $f_out
```

You can inline quite a few things if you want (e.g., the `subst` and template are reasonable candidates). If you end up pulling the input data from something that is a more generic format (e.g., CSV or JSON) then the parsing part is a little different — there are good packages that help — but the general pattern is recognisably similar.

Note that the template is processed by `subst`, and so internal braces are not significant. `subst`'s processing has a lot in common with using double quotes.

Comment: great , it works . fellow it genius & simple . thanks .